# JavaFX print text on multiple pages at once for duplex

Tags: javafx, printing

I m trying to print text and some lines that I put into a Group.

Depending on user action possible that it must be on multiple pages.
I tried many things all my Google links to this topic are marked as visited allready...

My problem is the thing with multiple pages .. i would like to do it without any scaling .. 
Its also possible that a Group is not the right thing for it ,
 but don´t know what would be better.

I hope somebody can help me ..
I added a short example of one way I tried it only prints one page...

```
public class Main extends Application {
private static Stage primaryStage; // **Declare static Stage**

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    setPrimaryStage(primaryStage);
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("SK");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1200, 800));
    primaryStage.show();
    drawStuff();

}
static public Stage getPrimaryStage() {
    return Main.primaryStage;
}
private void setPrimaryStage(Stage stage) {
    Main.primaryStage = stage;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}



Group[]  root=new Group[10];
public void drawStuff(){
    for(int i=0;i<=1;i++) {
        root[i]=new Group();
        final Text logo1 = new Text(60, 20, "TEST");
        logo1.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        logo1.setFont(Font.font(java.awt.Font.SANS_SERIF, FontWeight.BOLD, FontPosture.ITALIC, 18));
        root[i].getChildren().add(logo1);
    }
    print();
}
private void print() {
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();

        for(int i=0;i<=1;i++) {
            boolean success = job.printPage(root[i]);
            if (success) {

                job.endJob();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: it's possible that the solution is very easy , but I m a beginner in javaFX, I wanted to do soemthing that also runs on OSX

Comment: I found my mistake .. the job.endJob() should be after the for loop... solved----